# MySQL stored procedure not working on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, centos

I have the following stored procedure (Taken from a comment on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html, used to check if an index exists on a table):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_index_if_not_exists`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_index_if_not_exists`(table_name_vc varchar(50), index_name_vc varchar(50), field_list_vc varchar(200))
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

set @Index_cnt = (
select  count(1) cnt
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE   table_name = table_name_vc
and index_name = index_name_vc
);

IF ifnull(@Index_cnt,0) = 0 THEN set @index_sql = concat('Alter table ',table_name_vc,' ADD INDEX ',index_name_vc,'(',field_list_vc,');');

PREPARE stmt FROM @index_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The strange thing is that it works perfectly on CentOS 5.4 with MySQL 5.5.25, but does not work on Mac OS X 10.8.1 with MySQL 5.5.24. On Mac, the @Index_cnt is always 0 if I add

```
select @Index_cnt
```

in the stored procedure. If I do the `SELECT COUNT(1) cnt ...` statement on it's own, then 1 or 0 is returned as it should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you are certain that the underlying data is the same under CentOS and OSX?

Comment: Could this have something to do with the filesystem in CentOS being case-sensitive, whereas the OSX one isn't (secretly)?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes I am sure

Comment: @wkoot I just tested and it also does not work in Windows. Don't know that would help to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Windows is also insensitive. Are you able to check on another unix distro? Perhaps an ubuntu VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written the stored procedure and this now works on all platforms:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myschema.create_index_if_not_exists $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.create_index_if_not_exists(in p_tableName VARCHAR(128), in p_indexName VARCHAR(128), in p_columnName VARCHAR(128) )
BEGIN

PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT @indexCount := COUNT(1) from information_schema.statistics WHERE `table_name` = ? AND `index_name` = ?';
SET @table_name = p_tableName;
SET @index_name = p_indexName;
EXECUTE stmt USING @table_name, @index_name;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- select @indexCount;

IF( @indexCount = 0 ) THEN
  SELECT 'Creating index';
  SET @createIndexStmt = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ', p_indexName, ' ON ', p_tableName, ' ( ', p_columnName ,')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @createIndexStmt;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Use it as follows:

```
call myschema.create_index_if_not_exists('MyTable','end_time_index','end_time');
```

This was tested on MAC OS X 10.8.2 with MySQL 5.5.24 and on Windows 7 with MySQL 5.5.21